# urllib vs cloud storage (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parsing, google-cloud-storage, urllib

I'm developing an app (with Python and Google App Engine) that requires to load some content (basically text) stored in a bucket inside the Google Cloud Storage. Everything works as expected but I'm trying to optimize the application performance. I have two different options: I can parse the content via the urllib library (the content is public) and read it or I can load the content using the cloudstorage library provided by Google. My question is: in terms of performance, which method is better?

Thank you all.

Comment: test it and see. 'under the hood' they must be doing roughly the same thing, perhaps cloudstorage code is already somewhat optimised saving you effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the cloud storage. [URLLib has a lot of restrictions and quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Quotas_and_limits) that are in addition to that you would incur using the [cloud storage library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing). You also have more power, functionality and speed (as it makes internal calls) compared to urllib.

Answer (score 0):

They will likely be very close. the AppEngine cloud storage library uses the URL fetch service, just like urllib.

Nonetheless, like any performance tuning, I'd suggest measuring on your own.